# Автоматический запуск программ в Linux

Tags: linux, shell, cron

Есть небольшая консольная утилита написанная на C#. Необходимо запускать ее по расписанию на Linux сервере. Как я понимаю, для этого нужно использовать `crontab` и написанный на любом скриптовом языке файл, который будет запускаться в указанное время. Например если открыть `crontab -e` и добавить:

```
0 */1 * * * /home/username/script.sh
```

то каждый час будет запускаться скрипт `script`. 
Вопрос -
1) на каком языке лучше писать команды (php, python или еще каком). 
2) почему вот такой скрипт не работает, хотя при запуске утилиты вручную она выполняется отлично :

```
exec "/home/username/programm " && echo "programm start"
```

Comment: а зачем писать `exec "/home/username/programm " && echo "programm start"` а не просто `/home/username/programm`?

Comment: Не важно на скриптовом языке программа или нативная, крон все равно будет запускать.

Comment: @Ипатьев а нужен ли вообще скрипт? Вроде ж можно из кронтаба запускать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не нужен, я полагаю что в programm сама утилита

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Команда в кроне прописывается точно так же, как она вызывается из консоли - никаких скриптов или дополнительных команд писать не нужно.

То есть если утилита запускается командой `/home/username/programm`, то в кроне она должна писаться так же.

Если команда не работает, то узнать причину поможет отправка результатов выполнения крон команд на почту. Для этого в кроне необходимо заполнить переменную `MAILTO`:

```
MAILTO=user@example.com
```

весь вывод запускаемых команд будет приходить на эту почту.

Чаще всего причиной проблем является неверная работа с каталогами - использование относительного пути либо при вызове программы, либо внутри неё. чтобы избавиться от этой проблемы необходимо всегда писать полный путь к запускаемой утилите, и если нельзя исправить пути в самой программе, то перед вызовом сменить каталог

```
0 5 0 0 0 cd /home/username/ && /home/username/programm
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за офтоп, но не подскажите что я делаю не так - работаю с сервером через ISPmanager -> захожу в "Выполнить комманду" далее ввожу команда :` 'exec ConsoleApplication13.exe '`, каталог : `/fildername/` В ответ получаю сообщение : `cfocom:/cgaaf/$ exec ConsoleApplication13.exe
/bin/sh: 1: exec: ConsoleApplication13.exe: not found` Что не так делаю ?

Comment: То есть вы под линуксом хотите запускать утилиту, написанную для виндоус?

Comment: Хотелось бы, ведь на нем установлен `Mono`

Comment: Ну так надо тогда и компилировать программу под моно а не запускать виндовый экзешник. И вопрос надо было задвать не "как запустить программу под крон", а "как мне запустить программу на сишарп под линуксом"

Comment: На одном из форумов прочел что можно скомпилировать ексешник но запускать уже под `Mono` на сервере. Это действительно так ?

Comment: Я не работаю с C# и моно. как я уже сказал, вам надо задать совершенно другой вопрос, а не писать комментарии к этому.